# Быстрое преобразование Фурье

Tags: c#, фурье, алгоритм, fft

Здравствуйте! Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с преобразованием Фурье.
Код взят из википедии:

```
public static Complex[] fft(Complex[] x)
    {
        Complex[] X;
        int N = x.Length;
        if (N == 2)
        {
            X = new Complex[2];
            X[0] = x[0] + x[1];
            X[1] = x[0] - x[1];
        }
        else
        {
            Complex[] x_even = new Complex[N / 2];
            Complex[] x_odd = new Complex[N / 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < N / 2; i++)
            {
                x_even[i] = x[2 * i];
                x_odd[i] = x[2 * i + 1];
            }
            Complex[] X_even = fft(x_even);
            Complex[] X_odd = fft(x_odd);
            X = new Complex[N];
            for (int i = 0; i < N / 2; i++)
            {
                X[i] = X_even[i] + w(i, N) * X_odd[i];
                X[i + N / 2] = X_even[i] - w(i, N) * X_odd[i];
            }
        }
        return X;
    }
```

Подойдёт ли данная реализация FFT для использования с просто числами?
Допустим имеем массив double значений и всё что нужно - это перевести массив double в complex?

Проблемы: используются комплексные числа->как написал выше перебрать исходный массив к комплексной записи;
числа в массиве не являются степенями двойки->вот здесь не понял как решить.
В интернете все примеры что смог разобрать приведены или для чисел-степеней 2 или использующих "волшебные библиотеки".
Буду благодарен адекватному примеру или пинку в какую сторону копать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для представления complex значение сигнала (Ваш double) пишется в реальную часть, а в мнимую часть пишется ноль.

Степенью двойки должен быть размер массива, на содержимое таких ограничений не накладывается. Если у Вас массив имеет размер не степень двойки, то его придется либо обрезать до предыдущего значения степени двойки, либо дополнить нулями до следующего значения степени двойки.

Comment: Спасибо! Заработало!