# Ошибка при использование макроса Interop Excel c#

Tags: c#, excel, interop

Я пытаюсь использовать макрос для использования встроенного в Excel пакета анализа, а именно анализ Фурье.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По примеру кода для VBA, переделал его под C#, но что-то не работает:

```
Excel.Application Excel_file = new Excel.Application();

Excel.Workbook Excel_WorkBook;
Excel.Worksheet Excel_WorkSheet;
Excel.Range excelcells;

Excel_WorkBook = Excel_file.Workbooks.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
Excel_WorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)Excel_WorkBook.Sheets[1];

var voool = Excel_file.RegisterXLL("C:\\Users\\t.berdiev\\Desktop\\ADXL Ver 10\\ADXL 1\\ADXL\\analys32.xll"); 
Excel_file.AutomationSecurity = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutomationSecurity.msoAutomationSecurityLow;

//Тут заполнение ячеек

Excel_file.Run("ATPVBAEN.XLAM! Fourier", Excel_WorkSheet.Range["G2", "G4097"], Excel_WorkSheet.Range["Q2", "Q4097"], false, false);

Excel_file.Visible = true;
Excel_file.UserControl = true;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вроде бы включил макросы, в чем проблема не могу разобраться.

Comment: А почему именно эксель? C# не позволяет провести вычисления?

Comment: @aepot, я не нашёл адекватной реализации БПФ на C#

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/247385/, https://github.com/andrewkirillov/AForge.NET/blob/master/Sources/Math/FourierTransform.cs, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/725524/373567, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/947305/373567

Comment: вот еще https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/319963/373567 - плохо искали или это все не адекватные реализации?